# MvvmCross v5 animation between two root presentations

Tags: ios, animation, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have two iOS views marked by `MvxRootPresentation` attribute: `LoginView` without wrapping into navigation controller and `MainView` with wrapping into navigation controller.

When I call `ShowViewModel<MainViewModel>()` there is no animation between these two views. All subsequent views are animated as usual (within NavigationController).

How can I set animation for this transition?

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer below and accept it, instead of adding it as an update to your own question.

Comment: Done. My first question on stackoverflow :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I've did it myself :) I had to add my custom presentation attribute and custom presenter:

```
public class AnimatedRootPresentationAttribute : MvxRootPresentationAttribute
{
}

public class MyPresenter : MvxIosViewPresenter
{
    public MyPresenter(IUIApplicationDelegate appDelegate, UIWindow window)
        : base(appDelegate, window)
    {
    }

    protected override void RegisterAttributeTypes()
    {
        base.RegisterAttributeTypes();

        _attributeTypesToShowMethodDictionary.Add(typeof(AnimatedRootPresentationAttribute),
            (viewController, attribute, request) => ShowAnimatedRootViewController(
                viewController, (AnimatedRootPresentationAttribute)attribute, request));
    }

    private void ShowAnimatedRootViewController(
        UIViewController viewController,
        AnimatedRootPresentationAttribute attribute,
        MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        ShowRootViewController(viewController, attribute, request);
        AddAnimation();
    }

    private void AddAnimation()
    {
        var transition = new CATransition
        {
            Duration = 0.2,
            Type = CAAnimation.TransitionMoveIn,
            Subtype = CAAnimation.TransitionFromTop
        };

        _window.RootViewController.View.Layer.AddAnimation(transition, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me implement exactly the same behavior!

Comment: This is awesome. Note that the latest version defines the _attributeTypesToShowMethodDictionary dictionary as a protected property. Also note that this has the usual animation glitch when the new root VC is wrapped in a navigation controller, where the background goes black while it is animating in.